# Access Dictionary inside a list python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I created this List

```
counterDict = [
  ['countR0', {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}],
  ['countR1', {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}],
  ['countR7', {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}],
  ['countR12', {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}],
  ['countR14', {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}],
  ['countR17', {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}],
  ['countR18', {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}],
  ['countR19', {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}],
  ['countR20', {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}],
  ['countR21', {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}],
  ['countR22', {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}]
]
```

Basically what I'm doing is looping through the above using a our system software which contains some extra things not available in a normal python set. But regardless we use python 2.7 and what I'm doing is using the above as a counter. I need to count however a value (key) is seen in each row of bunch of different questions. I just can't seem to figure out how to access the above correctly. Just putting it in a python compiler and trying to access it and I'm getting confused as what it returns is not what I expect, so any help on how to access it properly would be very helpful. If I wrote it wrong, then please tell me.

Comment: This is what I get when I do this: counterDict[0] returns ['countR1', {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}] Which is expected, but then if I do this: counterDict[0][0] it returns 'countR0' which is what confuses me. Clearly I'm not doing something right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key can only occur once in a dictionary, so if you want to count keys, you will either get 0 (it doesn't exist) or 1 when it does exist.

To access the dictionary, `counterDict[0][1]` will give you `{0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}`. However what I think you want is this:

```
counterDict = {'R0': {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0},
               'R01': {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}}
```

Now you can do the following:

```
counterDict['R0'][0] # prints 0
```

To convert your existing list to this format:

```
counterDict = {r[0][5:]: r[1] for r in counterDict}
```

Comment: Ok That looks like what I am trying to do, let me give that a shot.

Comment: Everyone please upvote this, I can't because I don't have the rep, but it was the perfect answer :D

Answer (score 0):

`counterDict` is an list with 11 elements (it is not, as its name suggests, a dict)

Each element of `counterDict` is also an list, with two elements.

The first element of each element of `counterDict` is a string, the second is a dictionary.

`counterDict[0]` is an list:

`['countR0', {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}]`

Therefore `counterDict[0][0]` is the first element of that list: `'countR0'`

If you want the dictionary, you need

`counterDict[0][1]`:

`{0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}`

And an element of that dictionary:

`counterDict[0][1]['0'] ->  0`

I think you might have meant

```
counterDict = [
  {'countR0': {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}}
]
```

which would let you say

`counterDict[0]['countR0']['0']`

Comment: Those are actually *lists*, not arrays.  Python differentiates between the two because the list is a fundamental sequence type where as an array is an instance of [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#array.array).

Comment: Ok I see what I did wrong. Thanks, let me see if I can get that to work in the code I am using. :D

Comment: Ok so that's returning an error, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 2, in <module>
    {'countR0', {0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0}}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Gah - typo.   That line is a dict, so of course it's key and value are separated by a ':'